# How to get a border-bottom line with rounded corner

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get rounded corner underlines as you can see on the picture under "augmenter" and "visibilité sur internet".

[image]

I've achieved to do half of it as you can see in the snippet. But I cannot find a way to create a radius to the upper corner of my border-bottom (border-top-right/left-radius works only for border-top).

Do you have any solution ?
Thx in advance

```css
p{
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.primary-underline{
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #06CC6B;
  border-bottom-right-radius : 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius : 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>Nous aidons les artisans, commerçants, startups et PME à 
<span class="primary-underline">augmenter</span> leur 
<span class="primary-underline">visibilité sur internet</span></p>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element, placed behind the content, to create the underline effect.

Demo: (adjust values as needed)

```css
p{
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.primary-underline{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index:0;
}
.primary-underline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -5px;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid #06CC6B;
  border-radius : 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Nous aidons les artisans, commerçants, startups et PME à 
<span class="primary-underline">augmenter</span> leur 
<span class="primary-underline">visibilité sur internet</span></p>
```

Comment: you shouldn't forget to set z-index:0 to `.primary-underline` to keep the pseudo element in the stacking context of it's parent .. actually if we add a background to `p` the underline will be hidden.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Good call. Feel free to edit that in, since you edited out my mistaken duplicate `border-radius` :)

Comment: done, but wanted to add a comment so it's clear to anyone who will use it as this can be an annoying thing later ;)

Comment: you should set also `background-color` for Chrome & Co.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pseudo element:

```css
p{
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.primary-underline{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.primary-underline:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  height:10px;
  width:100%;
  border-radius:10px;
  background:#06CC6B;
}
```

```html
<p>Nous aidons les artisans, commerçants, startups et PME à 
<span class="primary-underline">augmenter</span> leur 
<span class="primary-underline">visibilité sur internet</span></p>
```

Or you can consider multiple background:

```css
p{
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.primary-underline{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, #06CC6B 98%,transparent 100%) bottom right/10px 10px,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, #06CC6B 98%,transparent 100%) bottom left /10px 10px,
    linear-gradient(#06CC6B,#06CC6B) bottom/calc(100% - 10px) 10px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<p>Nous aidons les artisans, commerçants, startups et PME à 
<span class="primary-underline">augmenter</span> leur 
<span class="primary-underline">visibilité sur internet</span></p>
```

And with some CSS variables to have better control:

```css
p{
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.primary-underline{
  --s:10px;    /* height of the line */
  --c:#06CC6B; /* color*/

  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) bottom right/var(--s) var(--s),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, var(--c) 98%,transparent 100%) bottom left /var(--s) var(--s),
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) bottom/calc(100% - var(--s)) var(--s);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<p>Nous aidons les artisans, commerçants, startups et PME à 
<span class="primary-underline">augmenter</span> leur 
<span class="primary-underline" style="--s:15px;--c:pink">visibilité sur internet</span> et aussi à <span class="primary-underline" style="--s:5px;--c:orange;">faire autre chose</span></p>
```